# Can a Windows 10 PC act as an iBeacon?

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm writing an app that will detect iBeacons in the proximity. I don't have any Beacons at the moment to test with and I only have one phone that will run the app. One idea is to use my laptop as the beacon.

My laptop has Bluetooth capabilities.
Windows 10 Pro

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, easy. You can try to use Bluetooth Framework for your testing purpose (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). Run Beacons demo.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I couldn't get it to work. The program ran but my phone didn't detect the Beacon.

Comment: Make sure that Intel drivers are uninstalled. If you have ANY third party Bluetooth drivers installed they will block ANY BLE functions on your PC.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I don't believe I have any 3rd party Bluetooth drivers. I can't see any under Device Manager.

Comment: Just checked with sniffer. All is fine. Easy to test if you have any sniffer or you can run Beacons demo on other PC and see that the packets are advertising.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko if you put all the steps and details in an answer and it works then I will select yours as the answer.

Comment: Nothing hard: You can use WireShark to capture raw Bluetooth packets (requires special hardware) to see advertising details. Or you can build Beacons demo. Copy it on other PC or leptop, click Open and then Start Monitoring. On firstPC also run Beacons demo, click Open and then Start advertising. On PC with monitoringyou can see all the advertising packets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free and open source [Windows Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/windows-beacon-library) to transmit iBeacon on Windows 10.  Here's C# code that uses the library to do that:

```
using Altbeacon;
using Altbeacon.Beacon;

BeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(new 
BeaconParser().SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .SetTxPower(-59)
    .SetManufacturer(0x004c)
    .SetId1("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6" /* proximity uuid */)
    .SetId2("1" /* major */)
    .SetId3("1" /* minor */).Build();
BeaconTransmitter.StartAdvertising(beacon);
```

Comment: Hi, when I tried to run the program I got an error: Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the target "\WindowsBeaconLibrary\bin\debug\WindowsBeaconLibrary.dll" is missing.

Comment: I've published a binary release of the dll file here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/windows-beacon-library/releases/tag/0.1

Comment: @davidgyoung I'm not a C# developer. Could you please update the repository with everything working as expected? I'm still getting the error:1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Repos\windows-beacon-library\WindowsBeaconLibrary\WindowsBeaconLibrary\BeaconParser.cs(475,41,475,65): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BluetoothLEAdvertisement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, @user1261710, we are in the same boat here.  I rarely do Windows development and my Windows license ran out a few months ago.  If any Windows developers read this and can help here, I'd be glad to collaborate.  I can be contacted through my profile page.

Comment: What is the manufacturer value of 0x004c?

Comment: 0x004c is the Bluetooth SIG manufacturer code for Apple, Inc.